# Who owns memory returned by MySQL Connector C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, memory-management, shared-ptr, mysql-connector

I'm having memory leak / deleting errors when using MySQL Connector C++ 1.05.

The Connector returns a pointer to a result set from executing query.

I am assigning the pointer to a `boost::shared_ptr`.  The call looks like:

```
std::string query_text;
query_text = /* ... */;
boost::shared_ptr<sql::Statement> query(p_db_connection->createStatement());
if (!query)
{
    return;
}
boost::shared_ptr<sql::ResultSet>  query_results(query->executeQuery(query_text));
if (!query_results->next())
{
    return;
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Who is responsible for deleting the
   allocated result set?
2. Should I be using `scoped_ptr` or
   `shared_ptr` if the results are only
   used within the function?
3. Is the result valid when another
   query is executed?

I'm using MySQL Connector C++ 1.05, MS Visual Studio 2008 version 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html) example, you're doing everything correct.

If you're using the `shared_ptr<X>` to store the result, it would be automatically disposed after your `shared_ptr` object goes out of the scope (in your case) / has no more actual references (speaking globally).

2) It depends, but the most common practice is to use the `scoped_ptr`, because it's contruction and memory deallocation is much faster and using it explicitly states, *that the object is valid for the current scope only*.

3) I am not sure I get the question correctly, but you could do `.reset` action for your `Results` and fill it with the new query result.

Also, I'm sure that your leaks are from memory allocated somewhere else *(could be in the library too)*. You might not be deleting something connector-related, see the docs.